# PDL compactness over nonstandard models

Tags: logic

Prove that PDL (Propositional Dynamic Logic) is compact over nonstandard models. That is, every finitely satisfiable set of propositions is satisfiable in a nonstandard Kripke frame. Conclude that there exists a nonstandard Kripke frame that is not standard.

You can find nonstandard Kripke Frame definition [here](https://books.google.pl/books?id=ZRXNOzX15d8C&pg=PA200&lpg=PA200&dq=nonstandard%20kripke%20frame&source=bl&ots=JdzwlGq06m&sig=tPsdc9OSlZRahUip9wHhLYEDhbI&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiVwsSjyavdAhWSJ1AKHZ0ECt8Q6AEwA3oECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=nonstandard%20kripke%20frame&f=false).

I bumped into this problem inside the book called "Dynamic Logic" by Harel, Kozen and Tiuryn. It is exercise 7.3 from the book. I have no idea how to approach it.

Comment: Could you please add explanations for the relevant terms, such as PDL or what it means for a Kripke frame to be nonstandard? Incidentally,  probably you mean "propositions" in your second sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have access to the book you mention.

In chapter 7, right after lemma 7.2 a nonstandard model $\mathfrak{N}$ is constructed, whose points are the maximal sets of consistent formulas. It's not hard to see that the Truth Lemma holds for this model, i.e. $s\models\varphi$ if and only if $\varphi\in s$(the proof is similar to the proof of the truth lemma for standard modal logic, for the non trivial part see e.g. Existence Lemma 4.20 in [Modal Logic](https://books.google.nl/books/about/Modal_Logic.html?id=-n7uBgAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y) by Blackburn et al.; maybe in the book you mention this is also shown but I didn't check). This model is the canonical (nonstandard) model of the logic given in the beginning of chapter 7.

Now let $\Sigma$ be a set of finitely satisfiable formulas. By soundness any finite set of formulas that is satisfiable is consistent. Therefore every finite subset of $\Sigma$ is consistent. Since the proof system given is finitary (i.e. proofs are finite) this means that $\Sigma$ is consistent. Therefore it can be extended in a maximal consistent set of formulas $\Sigma'$. $\Sigma'$ is a point in $\mathfrak{N}$ and by the truth lemma mentioned above $\Sigma'$ satisfies all the formulas of $\Sigma$, i.e. $\Sigma$ is satisfiable.

Now since PDL is not compact with respect to standard models (the set  $$\{\langle a^\ast\rangle p,\lnot p,\lnot\langle a\rangle p,\lnot\langle a\rangle\langle a\rangle p\ldots\}$$ is usually used as to show this) it follows that $\mathfrak{N}$ is indeed not standard.

Comment: Thank you very much. This solution is simply brilliant.